# Postgres pg_cron (cron.max_running_jobs valid range)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, pg-cron

Aurora Postgres 12.8

Created pg_cron job, everything looks good in cron.job, but the job actually didn't work and cron.job_run_details didn't get any record either.

RDS console log shows the following error

5 is outside the valid range for parameter "cron.max_running_jobs" (0 .. 0)

cron.max_running_jobs =5 in db, what should be the valid range/value for cron.max_running_jobs? and how to set it?

Wishes

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Holmestorm
Yes, fixed with AWS support ticket. set parameter 'max_worker_processes' =6.

DRS instance was very small so the default value for 'max_worker_processes' was 2, to have a job running parameter 'max_worker_processes' value should be greater than parameter 'cron.max_running_jobs'.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL_pg_cron.html#PostgreSQL_pg_cron.examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with AWS support ticket. set parameter 'max_worker_processes' =6.

DRS instance was very small so the default value for 'max_worker_processes' was 2, to have a job running parameter 'max_worker_processes' value should be greater than parameter 'cron.max_running_jobs'.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL_pg_cron.html#PostgreSQL_pg_cron.examples